# Comparing regression coefficients of different regions

Tags: r, regression, anova

I have to regress the average length of stay in a hospital $(Y)$ against infection risk $(X)$ for hospitals in four different regions with a linear regression model. With the `lm` function in R, I have found the regression coefficients for each of the regions but now they ask to check if the regression lines have the same coefficients. So I now constructed a model that makes a linear regression model for all the regions by using the following code in R:

```
combinedRegions.model  <-   lm(Stay ~ Region2Boolean + Region3Boolean
                            + Region4Boolean +  Infection + Infection:Region2Boolean + Infection:Region3Boolean + Infection:Region4Boolean, data = Data)
```

If I now want to check if the regression lines of the different regions have the same slopes, is it good to construct the following model

```
sameSlopes.model <- lm(Stay ~ Infection + Region2Boolean 
                    + Region3Boolean + Region4Boolean, data= Data)
```

and then perform an `anova` test on these models?

Comment: Your approach is OK.